# Deny email domains for registration forms

Tags: forms

Is there a simple way to block certain domains from the email part of a form?

I do not want mail.ru or nokia.mail to be able to register on my site.

```
$required_fields = array('email' => $lang['your_email'],
                         'username' => $lang['username'], 
                         'pass' => $lang['password'], 
                         'confirm_pass' => $lang['confirm_pass'], 
                         'name' => $lang['your_name'],
                         );
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if(array_key_exists(strtolower($key), $required_fields) && empty($value) )
        $errors[$key] = $required_fields[$key]." ".$lang['register_err_msg8'];
```

How would I customise this part?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You could always write the code to look at the email address, and see if it contains any of your "bad" domains?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very simple:

just use something like this:

```
$hostName = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_IP']); 
if(strpos($hostName, "nokia.mail") !== false || strpos($hostName, "mail.ru" !== false){
 die("We do not accept registrations from that domain."; 
}
```

If you get more domains than that to block, you'll want to use some array function, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
//inside of foreach loop ...

$blacklist = array("mail.ru", "nokia.mail");
$domain = explode('@', $email)[1];
if (in_array($domain, $blacklist)) {
  // anything else you wish to do
  continue;
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks guys going to try each now and see which one works best.

Comment: rm-vanda is simpler if you have one or two domains, this one uses arrays and is a bit more robust